# sbt shell vs. sbt console in intelliJ 2018.1.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

In intelliJ 2018.1.4 I am able to compile my scala source code within sbt console, by typing compile, then importing my main method and typing run.

```
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jun 1, 2018 11:28:44 AM
```

However, the same code produces the following error within sbt shell, or when i click the green arrow start button. 
any idea? which one should I trust?..

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: 
org.jetbrains#sbt-structure-extractor;2017.2: not found [error] unresolved 
dependency: org.jetbrains#sbt-idea-shell;2017.2: not found Project loading failed:
 (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sbt clean compile`?

Comment: no i havent - will try - what does it do?

Comment: It just runs clean and then compile. Since the error you're getting seems to be related to some intellij dependency, I suspect there's some conflict between the class files intellij is building and the class files sbt is building. Cleaning those out first might clear up the issue.

Comment: you could delete the **.idea** folder in your projects' root directory and open the project again in InteliJ.

Comment: check your `<home>/.sbt/0.13/` and `<home>/.sbt/1.0/` directories and delete any `idea.sbt` files you find. does it help?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. This fixed it:

1. Copy org.jetbrains folder from `/home/<username>/.IdeaIC2018.<version>/config/plugins/Scala/repo` to `/home/<username>/.ivy2/local`
2. Run sbt package or similar in the project to import on console to load all required sbt plugins
3. Import project in Intellij

Answer (score 0):

As observed by JetBrains' support line, reinstalling the Scala plugin also seems to make it work.